# Combining HTML form data with multi-friend selector

Tags: php, facebook, forms, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Having a heck of a time trying to figure out how to do this.

I'm trying to combine an HTML form of my making with a multi-friend selector so that people can, for example, choose an item with radio buttons, enter some text in a textarea and then use a multi-friend selector.

The form would store the items from my html form in a database while also sending out the request to the selected friend(s). I can't seem to find a way to combine FB's selector with my form so that, upon submission, I get POST info that combines the user ID's selected with the choices from my form.

Is this possible using any of FB's SDK selectors, or do I have to roll my own?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the from the [apprequests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) from the javascript sdk.  It will return an array called `request_ids` that you can use.

Comment: That's the problem...I need to combine a multi-friend selector with html form data. As far as I can see, there's no way using their dialog examples to integrate your own form data as there's no form action to POST to.